# Can't access $scope variables after changing view with $location.path

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access data that is on the $scope on a view where the app lands after clicking a button but it seems as if after using $location.path(url) to do the redirection the APP cannot see a variable that exists on the $scope anymore.

Form with the button:

```
<form ng-submit="getBrokenProbes()">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Bmonitor</th>
                    <th>Select Bmonitor</th>

                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="bmonitor in bmonitors">
                    <td>
                        <span>{{bmonitor.domainName}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getBrokenProbes(bmonitor)">Request</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('logmeinValidationCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location', function($scope,$http, $location){

        $scope.bmonitors = {};

        $scope.brokenProbes = {};

        $http.get('http://localhost/getBmonitors').success(function (data) {
            $scope.bmonitors = data;
            console.log($scope.bmonitors);
        });

        $scope.getBrokenProbes = function(bmonitor) {
            let url = 'http://localhost/getBrokenProbes';
            $http.post(url, bmonitor).then(function (response) {
                $scope.brokenProbes = response.data.hosts;
                console.log($scope.brokenProbes);
                $scope.showBrokenProbes();
            })
        };

        $scope.showBrokenProbes = function () {
            $location.path('/logmeinValidationResult')
        }

    }]);
```

I'm trying to show that data in a different view but $scope.brokenProbes is not available in logmeinValidationResult.html (the page where I land after $location.path) so it just shows an empty table.

logmeinValidationResult.html

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Probe name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="probe in brokenProbes">
            <td>
                <span>{{probe.description}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

New page controller:

```
app.controller('logmeinValidationResultCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        console.log($scope.brokenProbes); //This yields undefined
    }]);
```

Comment: Well, yes, it's undefined since you never defined it. The variable you defined was on the scope of a different controller. Each controller has its own scope (that's why it's called a scope). It seems your post request should in fact be a GET. So make the request from the second controller, not from the first one.

Comment: What @JBNizet said. Additionally, you can move your GET request to a service and get your value from there throughout your app: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. Otherwise you can use something like ui-router to pass state to different controllers. https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/state.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I)** The variable `$scope.brokenProbes` belongs to the controller `logmeinValidationCtrl` where is defined...
In order to use it inside another controller, you should pass it - broadcast.

**OR**

**II)** Another (Better) solution is when the user gets redirected to `logmeinValidationResult`, you can call the API, get the data and assign to `$scope.brokenProbes` variable.

In that case,
your old controller should look like this:

```
app.controller('logmeinValidationCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location', function($scope,$http, $location){

    $scope.bmonitors = {};

    $http.get('http://localhost/getBmonitors').success(function (data) {
        $scope.bmonitors = data;
        console.log($scope.bmonitors);
    });

    $scope.getBrokenProbes = function(bmonitor) {

       $location.path('/logmeinValidationResult/' + bmonitor); // Pass bmonitor to the result here so you can call the api with that parameter later on

    };

}]);
```

And your here is how your new page controller should look like:

```
app.controller('logmeinValidationResultCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$routeParams', function($scope,$http, $routeParams){

        $scope.brokenProbes = [];

        let url = 'http://localhost/getBrokenProbes';
        let bmonitor = $routeParams.bmonitor; // Get passed bmonitor value from the route params

        $http.post(url, bmonitor).then(function (response) {
            $scope.brokenProbes = response.data.hosts;
            console.log($scope.brokenProbes);
        })
}]);
```

And don't forget to register route param `bmonitor` to your $routeProvider or whatever you use...